# Python Add and Sort New Row into DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

I would like to add one row into the dataframe and I want to sort the dataframe after insertion.

I have added the row and reset the dataframe index but in vain.

How can I fix this problem? Thank you for advice in advance.

```
import pandas as pd

def diff(first, second):
        second = set(second)
        return [item for item in first if item not in second]

df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":[
                          '2015/12/25',
                          '2015/12/26',
                          '2015/12/27',
                          '2015/12/28',
                          '2015/12/29',
                          '2015/12/30',
                          '2015/12/31'
                        ],
                    "X":["X","A","A","X","","","X"]
                }) 

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Date":[
                          '2015/12/25',
                          '2015/12/28',
                          '2015/12/29',
                          '2015/12/30',
                          '2015/12/31'
                        ],
                    "X":["X","A","A","X",""]
                }) 

diff_df = pd.merge(df, df2, how='outer', indicator='Exist')

diff_df = diff_df.loc[diff_df['Exist'] != 'both']

prevDay = int(diff_df['Date'].values[0].rsplit('/', 1)[-1]) - 1
prevDate = diff_df['Date'].values[0].rsplit('/', 1)[-2] + "/" + str(prevDay)

df3 = pd.DataFrame({"Date":[diff_df['Date'].values[0]], "X":["Q"]}) 

df2 = df2.sort_index(axis=1, ascending=True)

df2 = df2.append(df3)

df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)

print(df2)
```

Actual Output:

```
0  2015/12/25  X
1  2015/12/28  A
2  2015/12/29  A
3  2015/12/30  X
4  2015/12/31   
5  2015/12/26  Q
```

Expected Output:

```
0  2015/12/25  X
1  2015/12/26  Q
2  2015/12/28  A
3  2015/12/29  A
4  2015/12/30  X
5  2015/12/31
```

Comment: Sure, thanks for your reference link.

Answer (score 0):

I think what want is pandas's [`searchsorted`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html) which return position to inserted into.

Sort values for every insertion sound bad. But if you only need to sort once after all inserts then it's fine.